# How to detect and prevent someone from using other's ip addresses?

Tags: networking, router, ip

We have a network setup in an organization in which everyone connected has a data usage limit related to their user login ids , where they first have to login to gain network access. Here automatically everyone is assigned a ip address via DHCP and hence usually there is no problems. But sometimes, after using up the data limit attached to their own user id's , one can change their ip address to a static one that someone else who is connected to the network is using and use their data.

So my question is how can a user detect whether his ip address is being used by someone else and if yes then how can this be prevented, both at the admin and user level? Also why does this not raise conflicts if same ip is being used by different physical machines?

Comment: Why not just check how long the user id has been logged on? Because if the user has exceeded the limit just deny them access to internet.

Comment: Yes they are denied access after the limit is hit,(it resets everyday). And herein lies the problem,  they change their ip address to someone else's who presumably are logged in and then get network access. This is what the question is.

Comment: Yes you don't get me. Let them have any IP that they want but ask them to login first to gain internet access. If they have exceeded the limit just deny them internet. Doesn't matter what IP they have their user ID and password will tell them that they have exceeded the daily limit. If we live in the same house and I'm logged into my facebook simply changing your ip to mine won't log you into my account. A lot of campings use this kind of security aswell. e.x PfSense

Comment: Another approach would be to establish GPOs or similar that prevent them from re-configuring their network settings.

Comment: They do have to login first to gain internet access on any ip. But if an ip has a user already logged on, and another person uses this ip he doesn't have to. There is a corporate firewall setup with restrictions on a user login id . But this is like, for example,  a logged in user opens a wifi hot spot, the users using that hot spot don't have to login. I hope you get the situation now.

Comment: Use proper network access control, including port-based security and whatnot. Alternatively, use a proxy with login required.

Comment: Use proxy with authorization and disable all outgoing connections on firewall, this way the only possibility to go online - through proxy. RamonRobben suggested a pretty good tool for that - [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) that has squid proxy as a package

Comment: I second the suggestion to enforce the host network settings by GPO rather than at the network device layer.

Comment: @Seth I understand we can enforce GPO in an Active directory environment. But there are heterogeneous systems on the network, i.e linux machines too. Can we enforce GPO still, or only on windows machines?

Comment: Naturally it wouldn't be the Windows GPO but there are probably similar tools available. Although it's probably going to be harder. With a heterogeneous network fixing the approach how a user is handled would probably be the better option. Others have suggested several approaches for it.